# Why are the Ghost and Bug types effective against the Psychic type?

Tags: pokemon

So one question I have about the Psychic type. Why are the Bug and Ghost types effective against the Psychic type?

I have been wondering this because I am on a quest to find the reason behind type effectiveness in *Pokémon*. I already know why the Psychic type is weak against the Dark type: because darkness absorbs psychic waves. As evidenced by the 8th Prayer against Giygas from *EarthBound*:

> Paula's call was absorbed by the darkness.

Comment: https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/492/70367

Comment: Also https://pokemondb.net/pokebase/149175/why-are-bug-type-moves-good-against-dark-and-psychic

Comment: It made the game more balanced.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Sounds like an answer to me...

Comment: I think OP is looking for the lore reason, not the gameplay reason.

Comment: Just to note that your reasoning for Psychic being weak to Dark is most likely wrong as the Dark type is the "Evil" type in the original Japanese - it exemplifies underhanded tactics and dirty fighting, rather than literal darkness.

Comment: Psychics can see ghosts, perhaps rendering them vulnerable. Bugs elude me.

Comment: It brings up the question "Why is bug even a type?". . . I can't think of what a "Bug" type move functionally even is. I can think of bites, stings, venoms, which are really just normal type moves or even poison.

Answer (score 4):

I do not believe that there is an official explanation, but [a fan theory](https://pokemondb.net/pokebase/149175/why-are-bug-type-moves-good-against-dark-and-psychic) is that both ghosts and bugs are common and powerful fears. As Dune states, "Fear is the mind-killer" and therefore Psychic is weak against these things that undermine it at a fundamental level.

> The Psychic type is based on the mind, and the mind has irrational fears, namely the dark, ghosts and bugs. That's why Psychic types are weak against those, but have a resistance to Fighting, because of the old "mind over substance" idea.

Comment: OOU, it's because Pokemon is an extended version of rock-paper-scissors-lizard-Spock, and it needs to be balanced.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis then they did a _very_ bad job of balancing it.

Comment: @OrangeDog Not arguing that.  The game mechanics provide cover for various imbalances.

Comment: The move 'Encore' should cause some damage to psychic types too, since public speaking is another common fear.

Comment: Hmm, Makes sense